# Using a 2d kernel on 1d input in a convolutional network

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio

I am trying to create a TasNet model, which is an audio separation network from the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.00541.pdf). In section 2.2.1 they discuss how the encoder is going to have a CNN and a Gate CNN. The operation presented is as follows:

w<sub>k</sub> = ReLU (x<sub>k</sub> ~ U) σ(x<sub>k</sub> ~ V)

where w<sub>k</sub> is a vector of weights for some basis signals, x<sub>k</sub> is the audio mixture so that x<sub>k</sub> ∈ ℝ <sup>1 × L</sup>, ~ is the symbol for the operation of convolution, and U, V ∈ ℝ <sup>N × L</sup>.

This is really weird because it implies, as far as I understand, that for the convolution of a 1d signal a 2d kernel is used. tensorflow does not support a kernel with more than one dimensions using `Conv1D`.

Am I misunderstanding something? If not, how can I convolve an 1d signal using a 2d kernel? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It does not need to be specific CON1D or CON2D, it is DATA input that transforms. I spend some time reading the paper you referenced and found they are talking about similar matching that is good practice for the neurons networks.

Practically you need a label and input for supervising learning but without the labels of the musical input ( I download sample from the Internet ) you can loops it over they can find similarities to themself.

The paper talks about encoder and decoder where that is the primary subjects of the signal, any model can work lstm, dense or CON1D, CON2D or CON3D practical logics.

**( 1 ) : Input**

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
samplerate, data = read("F:\\temp\\Python\\Speech\\temple_of_love-sisters_of_mercy.wav")
```

**( 2 ) : Windows ( hammings or extracts )**

By instants I am doing it now by fixed sizes windows

You can assign any value at the first stikes then updates back values of similarity if you do not provide the music instruments labels.

```
for i in range(10):
    input_array.append( np.reshape(sample_data[current_window:start_index ], (1, 147, 15, 1 )) )
    current_window = current_window - next_window
    start_index = start_index - next_window

label_array = [ ] 
for i in range(10):
    label_array.append( i )
```

**( 3 ) : Model** You can use any mnodel but I also using this for image catagorize cats from people and trucks objects.

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(88, 80, 1)),
            tf.keras.layers.Reshape((88, 80, 1)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (8, 8), strides=4, padding='same', activation='relu' ),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (4, 4), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu' ),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu' ),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), # layer_3
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
])

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(target, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.summary()
```

Complies and running ...
Don't forget to save weights and multiple rounds of training will find similarities.
He is working on it, your quesion it is like the games, no action in the begining until it repeating of action they try the actions (14)

Comment: First of all thank you for the time you took to read the paper and try to answer my question. However, I am having difficulties understanding your response. If I understand correctly you are reshaping the original data with shape (something,) to an array of shape (88, 80, 1). What motivated you to do so? The paper implies a convolution needs to be done on an audio segment x<sub>k</sub> of shape (1, L).

Comment: Input shape is one way to express when you using convolution 2D or 3D, you specific the matrixes properties and return. It is applicable to wave format, image format, and any sources with specific networks types as I told in the reply. 
Building networks or reshaping from the WAV format input is easy but labels it is one problem as said, the player does not know to do to target player until rounds of work and feedback. ** Think about sources or instruments you cannot create labels except repeating until they found some patterns **

Comment: The game image also doesn't have a label how they know the pattern, scores, or time, how about audio channels, it can be overlaps of sound within range ( conversation format ) or it can be sources specification but that is not your question.
How do you know single channels with multiple targets instrument overlap

Comment: It is already in the paper you mentioned!
Yes, it is !